# How widespread is "feetsubishi"?

Tags: idioms, kenyan-english

Today I've learned a perfect word "feetsubishi" - it's a playful term for describing pedestrian movement, here's quote [from](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=feetsubishi) urban dictionary:

> **feetsubishi** - an act of pedestrial walk due to lack of public or private transportation.

I've heard it from someone who lives in Kenya so my question would be - is it something that belongs just to Kenyan local variety of English or this word is used and understandable among the majority of English speakers throughout the world.

Comment: ti's the first time I've heard it, I was able to guess the meaning.  Mitsubishi is a well known automobile maker and the only common word that ends that way. So, understandable, but not used.  with many words you can grok the meaning from context :)

Comment: In the six/ seven years the UD entry has existed, only three visitors have given it their approval, a bit too little (for me) to confirm its status as English slang.

Comment: @Mari-LouA that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Well, isn't that confirmation that the term is relatively unknown? Google reports [only 36 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=feetsubishi&ei=yV9oWoXzMoeVUanTj9gC&start=30&sa=N&biw=1320&bih=620) for *feetsubishi*. There may be other ways of spelling it though.

Comment: @Mari-LouA no, it's giving a strong hint, but it does not a confirmation. It heavily depends on who and how often and for what purposes is using Urban Dictionary.

Comment: If I said I have never come across it once in 51 years, either in writing or in speech, would that be more convincing? :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA that would be a perfectly valid answer - and falls into the category of answers I'm looking for.

Comment: It comes to something when *Kenyan* English slang is more "high-tech" than mainstream UK/US slang! We still have to fall back on [Shanks's pony / mare](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shanks%27s_pony) if the car (or horse! :) won't start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In almost all the Anglosphere, the name of the Japanese automaker is [pronounced with a short i and the sh-sound](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KubUg-jqH7o), unlike the [Japanese pronunciation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOuyTFiVZus), where the first vowel is an English long e and the s and h are separate sounds.

For the pun *feetsubishi* to make any sense, at least the first syllable would have to be pronounced as it is in Japanese and Mitsubishi vehicles would have to have enough market share to be readily recognized.

That makes it likely something limited to Kenya, a localization reinforced by the relatively [few Google hits](https://www.google.de/search?q=feetsubishi&rlz=1C9BKJA_enDE701DE701&oq=feetsubishi&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.7598j0j8&hl=de&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) for the expression.

Comment: No.... the Japanese 'i' is more or less the same as the English 'i'. Furthermore, the 's' and the 'h' are not separate sounds. They form one mora with the 'i', 'shi' which in Japanese is し.

Comment: I'm just going by the youtube video.